# How to index into PSObject Array of Hashtables

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I'm working in powershell with an imported CSV. I have a data set like this:

```
  ID            First_Name                              Last_Nam
--              ----------                              --------
2314             Kenny                                   Anderson
21588            Mark                                    Anderson
2547             Ben                                     Andrews
5797             Benjamin                                Armour
```

Except with 2000 people and many more columns. Currently the data is stored as a series of hashes in a `@{ID = "..",First_Name:"..",Last_Name:".."}` and these are stored in a System Object array. I want to store each hash as an index in an array. I want to get the hashtable at that index, but I don't know how to into the System.Object Array. Here's my code:

```
$csv = import-csv $csv_name 
$row = @(0)*csv.length
$hash = @{}

for($i =0; $i -lt $csv.length; $i++){
$row[$i] += $csv[$i]
}

#error: cannot convert "@{ID : "..", First_Name: "..", Last_Name:".." to Systems.Int32

for($i =0; $i -lt $csv.length; $i++){
$csv[$i].psobject.properties | Foreach { $hash[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

$row[$i]+=$hash
}

#error: Cannot convert systems.collections.hashtable into Systems.Int32
```

I'm looking for a way to index the array so I can get the hashtable at that index. the The first one, with pointers to the hashtables accessible through the array, is what I think would be the easiest to manipulate. If there's an easier way to get a specific hashtable just from the System.Object[] itself, please tell me.

I should add I don't know the names or amount of the columns in advance.

Comment: `+=` is a terrible method to add to an array as it recreates and copies the entire array each time. The proper methods are 1) collecting the loop output `$arr = foreach (...) { .....; $element }` or 2) ArrayList. You can find more examples yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see you posted this in another question too, and I don't think it's good advice. In the vast majority of cases, the performance impact on the overall task is negligible or unnoticeable. `+=` is far more readable and clear, which is usually the more desirable trait. It's good to know the performance aspects of different ways of doing something, but to say `+=` is terrible and improper is a stretch, in my opinion.

Comment: @briantist, collecting output from loops or pipelines is simpler, faster, more readable, more 'poshy' even in case of small arrays.

Comment: @wOxxOm it can be, depending on the use case. Advocating replacing all instances of `+=` with a loop seems excessive to me. I respect your having an opinion on it I just feel the way you present it (`+=` is **wrong**, loop collection is **right**) could use some nuance. Would you say the same about string concatenation? That it should always be replaced with StringBuilder because `+` and `+=` recreates a string every time? (serious question, not being rhetorical)

Comment: @briantist, the case of `+=` with string is different: 1) it's simpler than StringBuilder while the opposite is true for the array case (with loop collection there's no need to initialize an empty array, no need to explicitly add the elements), and 2) compared to arrays strings are typically smaller/simpler, and the contents being a *primitive* data type is copied much faster.

Comment: Ah, @briantist, my rant was primarily about generating arrays from scratch, in which case += just makes no sense for the reasons I stated. I've clarified my point in that answer as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I'd agree with you in that case (usually). I think there are cases when you're filling multiple arrays based on criteria, where it makes more sense to do a single loop and add to the correct array, rather than iterate through the source twice to do it by assignment, but in the simple case I think you're right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `Import-Csv` is not an array of `[hashtable]`s, it's an array of `[psobject]`s, where each column is a property.

There's no need to build any kind of array to get an individual object by index.

```
$csv = import-csv $csv_name 
$csv[0]
$csv[1].First_Name
# etc
```

The errors in your code have nothing to do with the question you posed though; you're getting errors trying to add objects to an array, because you're actually trying to add an object or hashtable to an existing array element of type integer.

You don't need to precreate the array with a bunch of zeros, so this line isn't needed:

```
$row = @(0)*csv.length
```

Instead, you can create an empty array:

```
$row = @()
```

Then, you can just add to the array itself:

```
$row += $hash
```